# inserting data into mysql from user input

Tags: python, mysql

The following syntax works perfectly fine if hypothetically say there was another column named "age" and I was inserting data in two columns. But in this case it shows syntax error. So I assume a slightly different syntax would be used here?

```
db=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password='',database="cs")
c=db.cursor()
c.execute("create table if not exists leaderboards(idn int auto_increment primary key, name varchar(30))")

nm=str(input("enter your name"))
    
c.execute("insert into leaderboards(name) values(%s)",(nm))
db.commit()

c.close()
db.close()
```

Comment: This should be `(nm,)` to be a proper tuple.

Comment: thank you , that fixed it :)